# Why ArrayList<Integer> Contains is not working?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have:

```
ArrayList<Integer> onlyOne = new ArrayList<Integer>();
onlyOne.add(Integer.valueOf(3));

ArrayList<Integer> two = new ArrayList<Integer>();
two.add(Integer.valueOf(3));
two.add(Integer.valueOf(4));

boolean check = two.contains(onlyOne);
```

But this **always** returns false, why?

Comment: I think you need `containsAll` ? `Two.containsAll(OnlyOne);`

Comment: I've taken the liberty to adapt the variables to follow the Java naming convention in your question (and the top two answers): variables should start with a lower-case letter, only types (classes, interfaces, ...) and constants should start with an upper-case letter.

Comment: wow guys, why so much dislike on my question? I'm from C# and there we don't have ContainsALL, but anyway, thanks everyone. containsALL worked.

Comment: @Moondustt Because apparently you haven't read the documentation for ArrayList, List, or Collection. You should read the documentation first, then ask the question here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are checking if `Two` contains **the list `onlyOne` itself**.

`two.containsAll(onlyOne)` is what you need.

Comment: Thanks, as I work with c# and i'm trying to learn android, I thought contains would work in the same way, but containsall worked, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Because `two.contains(onlyOne)` is asking the question "Does `two` contain the object `onlyOne`?".  The answer is: "no".

For more success, try something like:

```
boolean check = two.contains(onlyOne.get(0));
```

or:

```
boolean check = two.containsAll(onlyOne);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the `contains()` method compares whether the argument you're passing is equal to some of the objects within the `ArrayList`.

This should return `true`:

```
ArrayList<Integer> OnlyOne = new ArrayList<Integer>();
OnlyOne.add(Integer.valueOf(3));

ArrayList<Integer> Two = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Two.add(Integer.valueOf(3));
Two.add(Integer.valueOf(4));

boolean ImCHECK = Two.contains(Integer.valueOf(3));
```

You may be interested to use the [ArrayList#containsAll(Collection c)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#containsAll%28java.util.Collection%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

you are not giving it an integer you are giving it the reference of an `ArrayList<Integer>`

you need to pull the integer out of `OnlyOne` using `OnlyOne.get(0)`

Comment: This is an example, I want something like this: Vector1 = 1,2,3,4,5
Vector2 = 2,3

Vector1.Contains(Vector2)

Because Vector1 has 2,3 and Vector2 too.

Comment: @Moondustt As other answers stated (the upvoted ones at least :) ), this is not the way `Contains` works.

Comment: @Moondustt: I'm pretty sure that [`List.Contains` in .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx) works exactly the same way!

Comment: List.Contains yes, LINQ contains nope, my mistake!

Answer (score 0):

boolean java.util.ArrayList.contains(Object o)

Returns true if this list contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this list contains at least one element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).

Specified by: contains(...) in List, Overrides: contains(...) in AbstractCollection
Parameters:
o element whose presence in this list is to be tested
Returns:
true if this list contains the specified element

Comment: Please also try to explain the issue, don't just copy what the documentation says (at least not for this question).

Answer (score 0):

OnlyOne is an instance of ArrayList not Integer

See java docs : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29